# Set role in JWT using java sprinboot. Using auth0-jwt library

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-data-jpa, jwt, auth0

I am trying to implment role based authentication in springboot.I cannot find a way to set role in JWT

Here is my code

**AuthService**

```
@Service
public class AuthService implements UserDetailsService
{
    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepo;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenProvider tokenProvider;

    public User registerUser(User user)
    {
        final String userName = user.getUserName();

        if(userRepo.existsByUserName(userName))
        {
            throw new HttpRuntimeException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT,"User already exsists");
        }
        else
        {
            user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
            return userRepo.save(user);
        }
    }

    public JWTForm loginUser(String userName, String password)
    {
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userName,password));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        // get token form tokenProvider
        return tokenProvider.generateToken(authentication);
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException
    {
        final User user = userRepo.findByUserName(username);
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new HttpRuntimeException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,"User not found");
        }
        else
        {
            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUserName(),user.getPassword(), AuthUtils.createAuthority(user.getRole()));
        }
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig
{
    @Autowired
    private AuthService authService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Autowired
    private JwtFilter jwtFilter;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder()
    {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    /*@Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService()
    {
        return new AuthService();
    }*/


    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider()
    {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authProvider.setUserDetailsService(authService);
        authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authConfig) throws Exception
    {
        return authConfig.getAuthenticationManager();
    }


    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint))
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/admin/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/admin/register").hasRole("ADMIN)
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

**JwtTokenService**

```
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider
{
    private final String jwtIssuer;
    private final long jwtValidity;

    private static Algorithm algorithm;
    private static JWTVerifier verifier;

    public JwtTokenProvider(@Value("${jwt.secret}") String jwtSecret ,@Value("${jwt.issuer}") String jwtIssuer ,@Value("${jwt.validity}") long jwtValidity)
    {
        this.jwtIssuer = jwtIssuer;
        this.jwtValidity = jwtValidity;

        algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret);
        verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).withIssuer(jwtIssuer).build();
    }

    public JWTForm generateToken(Authentication authentication)
    {
        final Date issueDate = new Date();
        final Date expiryDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + jwtValidity);
        final String userName = authentication.getName();
        final Set<String> role = authentication.getAuthorities().stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.toSet());
        // Create a JWT token with the given username and expiration time
        final String jwtToken = JWT.create().withIssuer(jwtIssuer)
                .withSubject(userName)
                .withIssuedAt(issueDate).withExpiresAt(expiryDate)
                .sign(algorithm);

        return new JWTForm(userName, role, jwtToken, issueDate, expiryDate);
    }

    private DecodedJWT verifyJWT(String jwtToken)
    {
        try
        {
            return verifier.verify(jwtToken);
        }
        catch (JWTVerificationException e)
        {
            throw new HttpRuntimeException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,"Invalid or expired accesss token");
        }
    }

    private DecodedJWT decodedJWT(String jwtToken)
    {
        try
        {
            DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode(jwtToken);
            return decodedJWT;
        }
        catch (JWTDecodeException e)
        {
            throw new HttpRuntimeException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,"Invalid or expired accesss token");
        }

    }

    public String decodeJWTClaim(String jwtToken)
    {
        try
        {
            DecodedJWT decodedJWT = JWT.decode(jwtToken);
            return decodedJWT.getSubject();
        }
        catch (JWTDecodeException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error");
//            return null;
            throw new HttpRuntimeException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED,"Invalid or expired accesss token");
        }
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token)
    {
        return verifyJWT(token) != null;
    }
}
```

I cant add role into the JWT data. How do i do that, thanks in advance. I use DAO authentication with a user Table that has a role field with type String. I just convert it to Set of Roles and pass it into UserDetails